# Putting Space Between Strings

Tags: string, powerbi-desktop, space

I am trying to put a space at specific intervals in a string. For example,

RedBlueYellowGreen

Is it possible to create a formula to recognize to put a space between 'Red, 'Blue,' 'Yellow', and 'Green.'

I came across one option that used the Advanced Editor, but it returned an error because the original data had been pulled from an outside source. Having a second 'let' statement created the error.